# Record the performance test of open unity executable file on photon cloud multiple times

Tags: cloud, performance-testing, photon

I have a build/executable file of the unity multiplayer application which provided me from my colleague and asked me to run/record the performance test of this exe file on "Photon Cloud Server" like:

1. Open the exe file on photon cloud single/multiple times and find the performance.
2. Increase the number of ccu and calculate the performance.
3. Generate report.

So, through this link "https://doc.photonengine.com/en-US/server/current/applications/photon-control-application" I have installed "Photon Control" on my system and follow the below mention steps to try to record the performance test:

1. Stop Photon if it's running
2. From Photon Control -> Performance Counters -> Install Counters, Create Logging Set
3. start "perfmon" from command line. Under "data collector sets" -> "User Defined": choose the photonperflog in the RIGHT window pane -> Properties -> set the sample interval to 1 second (the default of 1 minute does not give us enough data here)
4. start Photon
5. Photon Control -> Performance Counters -> Start Logging
6. run load test
7. Photon Control -> Performance Counters -> Stop Logging

I have run same steps as mentioned above and generate the performance monitor as below:

[image]

but I didn't get that, this performance monitoring is for "Unity App" or for my local computer and how can I open the exe file of my app on photon cloud multiple times, how to add the CCU in it and generate report to present

I am new in unity and photon cloud

Comment: Hi @user88, thank you for choosing Photon! Not sure if you are asking about how to properly use performance counters OR how to properly do stress tests in Photon Server. In any case, start with the documentation [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/current/performance/photon-counters) and [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/current/performance/performance-tests

Comment: Yea,@JohnTube I have used both link but the information is not clear for the users new in photon, simple I want to record a stress test for my unity standalone app on photon cloud, I have tried since last 2 to 3 days to do it but I am fail to get how to open multiple client/instance of the standalone app, how to set concurrent users in it

Comment: Customers usually get in touch via developer@photonengine.com to get a framework for load test on their own servers. To do load test on the cloud you need to have a private or enterprise one. Both options are not free. Otherwise, you are on your own and you need to figure it out. As stated in the performance test documentation page those tests are done server-to-server and not clients to server.

Comment: Thanks @JohnTube can you provide us with a trial of this cloud base framework, so we can prepare testing environment and do some kind of a test implement on it

Comment: I'm not in the position to do so. Send an email with your request and details about your project